# django debug toolbar uploaded badly

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

just starting using Django (first project) and I wanted to install the Django Debug Toolbar.
I did exactly as the installation guide in the documentation here said:
[Django Debug Toolbar Docs- Installation](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)

For some reason the page loads like this:
[image]

The html file that is loaded is a simple but legit one and ill add it here:

```
<html>
<body>
    {% if name %}
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    {% else %}
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    {% endif %}
</body>
```

BTW: Removing the if statements is not working either, also not working on both chrome and firefox.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
This worked for me.

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    from django.urls import path, include

    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
    INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1',)
    INSTALLED_APPS += ['debug_toolbar']
    MIDDLEWARE += ['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']
```

Comment: I did it and now all the toolbar is gone from HTML, but still doesn't show at all, when I inspect the page I can see it is attached to the HTML file but it looks like it's hidden. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from @AlexElizard and mixed it with some other user answer from coding with mosh forum:

1. In Windows, edit the registry `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type` from `text/plain` to `text/javascript` using Registry Editor. (Doing this alone didn't help.)
2. Clear cache of the browser.

And now it works just fine.